# oracle get variables from plsql back to linux

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, sqlplus

When sending variables from linux command to a plsql block, i am calling the program as sqlplus user/pass@db @file param1 and within the file i can use the param1 as &1.
Now what happens on the other way around? If you want to have a file which will execute sth. sqlplus user/pass@db and inside this file you have select number from table and this results to a single number out. 
When this executes, how can i send this number back to linux so that to use it within my sell script? 
i.e. export NUMBER=the number i got from sql

Comment: You can't. sqlplus does not return values back to the shell. search google for ways to execute shell commands from plsql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using here document:

```
v1=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -S /nolog > ${logfile} 2>&1 << EOF
connect test/passwd@sid
SET FEED OFF;
SET TERMOUT ON;
SET VERIFY OFF;
SET ECHO OFF;
SET HEAD OFF;
SELECT sysdate from dual FROM DUAL;
EXIT
EOF`

echo $v1
```

Comment: Can the values of Username, Password and instance be substituted with variables like for example: connect test/passwd@sid -> connect $User/$Pass@$dbinstance ?

Comment: Yes you can. In the text you send into the here document you can user unix varriables.

Comment: @Robert.. I have another question with title: data pump query with sql inside to_timestamp with subquery  ..On the 2nd edit of that question i wrote  an idea which is similarly based on  this. So if you can have a look on that question and if my syntax is correct you can answer that as well. Thanks a lot